# Date conversion: Converting dates that contain day of the week to a normal date format

Tags: r, date

I've got a dataframe that has the day of the week contained the same field as the D/M/Y, I'm trying to convert it into the traditional format without the day of the week. Dataframe format as follows:

```
Date: chr [1:9] "Tuesday 4 October 2022" "Wednesday 5 October 2022" "Thursday 6 October 2022"
```

I would have liked to simply convert that to a more usable format using:

```
as.Date(df&Date, format = ("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

But unfortunately I'm getting errors:

```
Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”
```

Any advice on how to change this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `parse_date` to automatically detect the format and convert to Datetime format, which is converted to `Date` class with `as.Date`

```
library(parsedate)
as.Date(parse_date(str1))
[1] "2022-10-04"
```

Or if we want to use the `base R`, make use of the correct format i.e. `%A` - for the weekday, `%d` - for day, `%B` - for month name and `%Y` - for 4-digit year

```
 as.Date(str1, format = "%A %d %B %Y")
[1] "2022-10-04"
```

For the whole Date column

```
df$Date <- as.Date(parse_date(df$Date))
```

Or

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%A %d %B %Y")
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "Tuesday 4 October 2022"
```